# What are the busiest times in Berlin?

Tags: hotels, berlin, events

I want to travel to Berlin several times in the next few months. I want to avoid the busiest times, when there are big events like IFA or Berlin Marathon because hotels get more expensive then.

Is there a reliable and comprehensive list of (only) big events that influence hotel availability and prices considerably?

Sure I can find lists of all events, but then I don`t know which are the dangerous ones...